# Datatable is not getting filtered / reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using JQuery Datatable plugin processing serverside and it is not getting refreshed when the dropdown is changed. I will be sending a value through datatable to my PHP class which fetches the records from the backend. then the scenario is whenever the dropdown is changed, the table will be sorted according to the value has been selected. The way I am trying to do now is not even firing when the dropdown is changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Initially gets the selected value of dropdown
    var status= $("#orderStatus option:selected").text();

    //DataTable Initialization
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tableone = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing":   true,
            "serverSide":   true,
            "paging"    :   true,
            "searching" :   true,
            "sDom": 'rtip',
            "iDisplayLength"    :   100,
            "processData": false,
            "ajax": {
                url  :"fetch.php",
                type : "POST",
                data : {
                    status: status
                }
            }
        } );

        //Search field
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            tableone.search($(this).val()).column(0).draw() ;
        });
    } );

    //Whenever the value is changed, the table has to be sorted acc to its value.
    $(document).on('change','#orderStatus',function(event){
        var drpStats= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url  :"filter.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                status : drpStats
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And there is another way I am trying  out, in that the dropdown is being fired when its changed, but doesn't fetch the values. that is attached too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var status= $("#orderStatus option:selected").text();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableone = $('#exampleone').DataTable( {
        "processing":   true,
        "serverSide":   true,
        "paging"    :   true,
        "searching" :   true,
        "sDom": 'rtip',
        "iDisplayLength"    :   100,
        "processData": false,
        "ajax": {
            url  :"fetch.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                status: status
            }
        }
    } );

    $('#search').keyup(function(){
        tableone.search($(this).val()).column(0).draw() ;
    });

    $("#orderStatus ").on('change', function() {
        var drpStats= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url  :"filter.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                status: drpStats
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    });
} );
</script>
```

This way I am getting the changing value of the dropdown but the datatable is not getting filtered once it is changed. What might be the reason? In the console it is returning both fetch.php and filter.php's JSONS. The solution might be simple. but I couldn't reach where am I making the mistake. Please comment if more info is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of hustles, I figured out that when the datatable is initialized, the passing data should be straightly taken from the dropdown instead of assigning the changing value to a variable and pass that data on.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Initially gets the selected value of dropdown
    var status= $("#orderStatus option:selected").text(); //This is unnecessary.

    //DataTable Initialization
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tableone = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing":   true,
            "serverSide":   true,
            "paging"    :   true,
            "searching" :   true,
            "sDom": 'rtip',
            "iDisplayLength"    :   100,
            "processData": false,
            "ajax": {
                url  :"fetch.php",
                type : "POST",
                //It's changed here
                data : function(data){
                    var status = $('#orderStatus').val();
                    data.orderStatus = status;
                }
            }
        } );

        //Search field
        $('#search').keyup(function(){
            tableone.search($(this).val()).column(0).draw() ;
        });

       //Then Redraw the datatable when the dropdown is selected
            $('#orderStatus').change(function(){
            tableone.draw();
        });
    });
```

and on the serverside receive the dropdown as it is posted

```
$orderStatus = $_POST['orderStatus'];
```

Reference: https://makitweb.com/how-to-add-custom-filter-in-datatable-ajax-and-php/?unapproved=13009&moderation-hash=c02720a3cdf60b2886fed5a45824b850#comment-13009